# How to upgrade from Magento 2.2 to 2.3 with Ultimo Theme Installed?

Tags: magento, themes

I've fully working Magento 2.2 and latest Ultimo Theme, now I must upgrade to Magento 2.3 to continue to receive the support but Ultimo Theme has file for Magento 2.2 and file for 2.3 version.

Which is the correct and simple way to upgrade?

Thanks.